# Zsh Behavior Until Loop Variable Behavior

Tags: loops, variables, echo, zsh

```
#!/bin/zsh

sqlday0="2020-10-10"
sqlday1="2020-10-11"
sqlday2="2020-10-13"
sqlday3="2020-10-14"
sqlday5="2020-10-15"
sqlday6="2020-10-16"

i=0
until [[ $i -gt 5 ]] do
    var1=\$sqlday$i 
echo $var1 
echo "$sqlday0"
    ((i=i+1)) 
done
```

> Terminal:

```
$sqlday0
2020-10-10
$sqlday1
2020-10-10
$sqlday2
2020-10-10
$sqlday3
2020-10-10
$sqlday4
2020-10-10
$sqlday5
2020-10-10
```

My goal here is to loop thru $sqlday0, $squlday1...etc and output the respective date that variable is assigned to. But why does the shell not return each variable $sqlday[0-5] as the each respective date? When I echo "$sqlday0" it references the global variable but the loop has a problem--why is this and how do I get this to work? I just echo'd $sqlday0 manually because I wasn't sure why the echo $var1 wasn't retrieving the date in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, you are doing a

```
echo "$sqlday0"
```

which means that you always print the value of the same variable, `sqlday0`. Since you never change the content of this variable, I don't see why you expect a different value on each iteration.

What **does** change inside the loop is the content of `var1`, so if you do a

```
echo ${(P)var1}
```

you will see different sqlday-values on each iteration. Or course a better solution would be to use an **array** sqlday instead of a scalar, so that you can refer to the individual days by `$sqlday[$i]`, which also obviates the need to use a helper variable `var1` for doing the indirect reference.